# How to iterate a spatraster faster using 'terra'

Tags: raster, r, terra

I try to use the phenological data and soil moisture data from 2000 to 2018 to judge this question: whether a certain day before a specific phenological period is too wet, the standard is that the soil moisture of that date is above the 90th percentile of the soil moisture sequence from 2000 to 2018.

My current code idea is: traverse the phenological data of the current year, read the phenological period of each pixel, such as 100; if the previous period is 1 day, then I need the soil moisture sequence of the 99th day from 2000 to 2018, and then judge this sequence, get the result, and assign it to the empty data prepared in advance, but this is really too slow, how can I improve it?

```
phe_data_path = phenology_path
phe_data_lis = phenology_list

climate_data_path = climate_variable_path
climate_path_lis = list.dirs(climate_data_path)

for (i in 1:length(phe_data_lis)){
  year = i + 1999
  phe_rast = rast(phe_data_lis[i])
  res = phe_rast
  res[] = NA
  
  dir.create(outputpath)
  
  for (j in 1:120) {
    
    ago_days = j
    
    for (k in 1:ncell(phe_rast)){
      
      phe = phe_rast[k]
      phe = as.numeric(phe)
      
      if (is.nan(phe)||is.na(phe)){
        res[k] = NA
      }else{
        
        doy = as.numeric(phe) - ago_days
        
        if (doy < 0) {
          start = 1
          
        }else{
          start = 2
        }
        
        end = start + 18
        
        cli_path_lis = climate_path_lis[start:end]
        data_path_list = c()
        
        for (z in 1:length(cli_path_lis)){
          
          t =paste0(cli_path_lis[z],'/',gtools::mixedsort(list.files(cli_path_lis[z],pattern = '.tif$')))[doy]
          
          data_path_list = append(data_path_list,t) 
          
        }
        
        cli_stack = rast(data_path_list)
        
        cli_list = cli_stack[k]
        
        if (sum(is.na(cli_list))>0){
          res[k] = NA
        }else{
          
          threshold = quantile(cli_list,0.9,na.rm = TRUE)
          if (cli_list[i]>threshold){
            
            res[k] = TRUE
            
          }else{
            
            res[k] = FALSE
            
          }
           
        }
        
      }
      
    }
    
    writeRaster(res,outputpath))
  }
}
```